# C - unknown type name PRAWINPUTDEVICELIST even though Windows.h is included

Tags: c, windows, gcc, raw-input

I am using GCC on Windows 10 to compile C program.

I have included `Windows.h` to access the Windows Raw Input API.

```
#include "Windows.h"
```

In my `main` function I am using a few types and functions from that header file.

```
UINT numDevices;
PRAWINPUTDEVICELIST devices;
if (GetRawInputDeviceList(NULL, &numDevices, sizeof(RAWINPUTDEVICELIST)) != 0) return 1
if ((devices = malloc(sizeof(RAWINPUTDEVICELIST) * numDevices)) == NULL) return 1
if (GetRawInputDeviceList(devices, &numDevices, sizeof(RAWINPUTDEVICELIST)) == (UINT) -1) return 1
```

When I try to compile it says `error: unknown type name 'PRAWINPUTDEVICELIST'` even though the header file is working fine... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use `#include <windows.h>` because it is not in your current directory.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie That is not making any difference...

Comment: How do you compile it? Also, are you using Mingw64 or the old Mingw?

Comment: I compile by doing `mkdir o` `cd o` `gcc -c ../src/*.c -Wall`. I'm using Mingw and never had problems even though my computer is 64 bit.

Comment: Wow! I just read this. "MinGW is a GCC-port for Windows. Not all of the Windows API is supported"

Comment: I switched to mingw64 and everything is now working! Thanks for the help